# XAML Binding to parent of data object Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, object, parent-child, xamarin.forms

Xamarin Forms (XAML): How do I access the “parent” data context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `{x:Reference parent}` markup?

I'm new at this myself, but if your element requires element to only one element (the parent in your case), you should be able to specify it.

In this example, you'd have to replace `label` by the parent element and from there the `Binding` would reference the right object.

```
<Slider x:Name="rotationXSlider"
        BindingContext="{x:Reference label}"
        Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"
        Maximum="360"
        Value="{Binding RotationX, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
```

Reference:
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/xaml-for-xamarin-forms/data_binding_basics/

Comment: This is a correct answear. For example to send a clicked URL in a ListView to the ClickedCommand in the View Model: <TapGestureRecognizer
                                            Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference nameOfContentPage}, Path=BindingContext.ClickCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding Url}"/>

Answer (score 3):

I found the 'nice' way to do this in Xamarin is to name the 'root' BindingContext on each page:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <AViewModel x:Name="RootContext" />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

And then reference it in the element that is needed, without having to set an individual BindingContext. For example:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference RootContext}, Path=StopCommand}"/>
```

A binding context is OTT sometimes, because everything below inherits it (sometimes without you knowing).